# Traverse through a json field in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table called all_measures with a field called measures that contains a json structure

```
{ "Composition" : { "Sales" : 85, "Trend" : 64, "Index" : 76, "Week" : 61 }, "Stores" : { "Sales" : 85, "Trend" : 64, "Index" : 76, "Week" : 61 }, "Online" : { "Sales" : 85, "Trend" : 64, "Index" : 76, "Week" : 61 } }
```

I'm want to traverse this json and in 2 columns, have the path and the kpi.

This is what I have been able to do with my SQL.

```
SELECT  json_object_keys(fct.measures) path,
        json_object_keys(fct.measures::json->'Online') kpi
FROM all_measures market fct
```

Result:

```
          path          |           kpi                       
------------------------+------------------------
 Composition            | Sales
 Stores                 | Trend
 Online                 | Index
                        | Week
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve. How do I get to this result?

```
     path               |           kpi                       
------------------------+------------------------
 Composition            | Sales
 Composition            | Trend
 Composition            | Index
 Composition            | Week
 Stores                 | Sales
 Stores                 | Trend
 Stores                 | Index
 Stores                 | Week
 Online                 | Sales
 Online                 | Trend
 Online                 | Index
 Online                 | Week
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=afc4fc1fbdad4239a55c3f213676bb70)

Reuse the `json_object_keys()` with the first run:

```
SELECT 
    path,
    kpi
FROM mytable,
    json_object_keys(mydata) as path,
    json_object_keys(mydata -> path) as kpi
```

Comment: this helped a lot, thanks for taking your time to asnwer my question. Ended up going with your approach. But out of curiosity, between the cross join and your approach which one is more efficient at scale?

Comment: Well, the , character is just a shortcut for `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`. So, in fact, I believe it's hard to say and depends on your environment, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cross join`

```
SELECT m.path, x.kpi
FROM all_measures fct
  cross join jsonb_each(fct.measures) as m(path,v)
  cross join jsonb_each (m.v) as x(kpi,val)
order by m.path
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a866fb1cbbde6108bdc044b3143e5279)

Comment: when I run your code in my DB, I get ERROR: function jsonb_each(json) does not exist. When I change it to json_each(fct.measures) I get ERROR: cannot deconstruct a scalar

Comment: @Malyk: well apparently your column is defined as `json` not as `jsonb` (which it should be). You need to cast it `jsonb_each(fct.measures::jsonb)` - but the error message "*cannot deconstruct a scalar*" means that you have data in that column that looks different to the one you have in your question

Comment: you're right I casted to jsonb and fixed the data in the columns. It works now thanks